# engineStrict: true does nothing

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a project where I want to be sure everyone use the same node and npm version.

So I added:

```
  "engineStrict": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">= 4.5.2",
    "node": ">= 0.10.40"
  },
```

The npm version I added there actually does not even exist yet.

However when running `npm install` nothing happens.

I would like `npm install` to fail explaining the user he needs at least `4.5.2` npm version. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you read this: http://www.marcusoft.net/2015/03/packagejson-and-engines-and-enginestrict.html

Comment: yes @limelights it seems to answer my question :) however I don't like the workaround the author propose so if there's anything better that can be done i'll leave that question open for the future...